# Trying to create multiple instances of an object and print their info

Tags: java, oop, object

Trying to create a program that features the stats of NFL teams. The "Team" class creates the objects and the main method would print the stats. When I try to print the stats, all teams will only print the attributes of the last team. So when I try to print Arizona, it prints Buffalo. Heres the code:

```
//Team class that creates the Team Objects
public class Team {
    public static int offenseRating;
    public static int defenseRating;
    public static int kickerRating;
    public static String teamname;

    public Team(String teamname, int offenseRating, int defenseRating, 
    int kickerRating) {
        Team.teamname = teamname;
        Team.offenseRating = offenseRating;
        Team.defenseRating = defenseRating;
        Team.kickerRating = kickerRating;
    }

    static Team Arizona = new Team("Arizona Cardinals", 50, 50, 50);
    static Team Atlanta = new Team("Atlanta Falcons", 50, 50, 50);
    static Team Baltimore = new Team("Baltimore Ravens", 50, 50, 50);
    static Team Buffalo = new Team("Buffalo Bills", 50, 50, 50);


public class footballMain {
//Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(Team.Arizona.teamname);

    }
}
```

Comment: because fields in your `Team` class are static. And all your instances share same static variables. For every team it will be `Buffalo` because `Team Buffalo` static field will be initialized as the last one.

Comment: Moreover names of your static variables (e.x `Team Buffalo`) are not allowed and this code will not even compile. They contain a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` means that "all instances of the class will share the same variable". This means when your constructor gets called, you are changing the value each time. Thus, only the last team persists.

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-static-and-non-static-variables-in-java/) is a good resource for learning `static` vs `non-static`

To  fix this, you should just remove the static modifiers of

```
public static int offenseRating;
public static int defenseRating;
public static int kickerRating;
public static String teamname;
```

and use `this.` in your constructors instead of `Team.`

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the static keyword from the fields and from the constructor.
Try this one here:

```
//Team class that creates the Team Objects
public class Team {
   public int offenseRating;
   public int defenseRating;
   public int kickerRating;
   public String teamname;

   public Team(String teamname, int offenseRating, int defenseRating, 
   int kickerRating) {
       this.teamname = teamname;
       this.offenseRating = offenseRating;
       this.defenseRating = defenseRating;
       this.kickerRating = kickerRating;
   }

   static Team Arizona = new Team("Arizona Cardinals", 50, 50, 50);
   static Team Atlanta = new Team("Atlanta Falcons", 50, 50, 50);
   static Team Baltimore = new Team("Baltimore Ravens", 50, 50, 50);
   static Team Buffalo = new Team("Buffalo Bills", 50, 50, 50);

//Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.print(Team.Arizona.teamname);
}
```

The this keyword means to write the value of the constructer argument to the field of the current instance.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out, the static variables are 'Class variables' that are always accessible when they have been declared. They are very often used to declare constants about your program (You should check the Enum structure that could fit your needs to). The fields of a class are 'Instance variables' and they purpose is to keep a specific state of a specific data structure created in memory. It is important to protect those memory spaces for security reasons.

A very good way to not reproduce this error is to focus on the use case of the data --> The same forever then static; A specific variable fo a specific object (instance of a class) then instance variable.

Here is a code to illustrate this and that compiles

```
package Question_5669067;

import java.util.Objects;

public class Team
{
    // We ensure that the static variable Buffalo will never change.
    public final static Team Buffalo = new Team("Buffalo Bills");

    // We protect the instance class from calling code.
    private String teamName;
    private int offenseRating;

    public Team(String teamName){
        this.teamName = Objects.requireNonNull(teamName, "Null teamName");
    }

    // We ensure that the String name is returned.
    public String getTeamName() {
        return this.teamName;
    }

    public int getOffenseRating(){
        return offenseRating;
    }

    // We ensure that the rate could not get under 0.
    public void setOffenseRating(int offenseRating){
        if (offenseRating < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rate < 0");
        }
        this.offenseRating = offenseRating;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Team.Buffalo.getTeamName());
        // Whe are still within the class,
        // so we can reach the team name directly.
        System.out.println(Buffalo.teamName);
        Buffalo.setOffenseRating(13);
        System.out.println(Buffalo.getOffenseRating());
    }
}
```